# Is List<T>.BinarySearch the fastest way?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I encountered programming code finding an item in the list. When I asked why using this code, they say because this works faster.

Is this true?

```
public static Location GetRecordById(this List<Location> records, int? id)
{
    if (id == null) return null;
    int position = records.BinarySearch(new() { Id = (int)id });
    return position >= 0 ? records[position] : null;
}
```

Faster way than

```
public static Location GetRecordById(this List<Location> records, int? id)
{
    if (id == null) return null;
    return records.FirstOrDefault( w => w.Id == id );
}
```

Comment: Have a read of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: A binary search is `O(log n)`, while a linear search is `O(n)`.  However, a binary search assumes the collection is already sorted, if it isn't sorted, you need to take into consideration the time to sort the collection as well.

Comment: If lookup by the id is an important performance-critical operation: consider using a `Dictionary<int, Location>` instead, and `TryGetValue` - then it is `O(1)`

Comment: @MarcGravell the `Dictionary<int, Location>` is faster, but at the cost of increased memory footprint (more or less +12 bytes per item).

Comment: A binary search not only requires that the collection is already sorted, but that elements even *can* be compared. Not every type has a natural sort order.

Answer (score 2):

It is faster, but only works if:

- the `Location` class implements `IComparable` and defines "greater than" and "less than" based on the value of `Id` and
- The list is already sorted by `Id`

Meaning it does not work with any arbitrary list or if you want to find a value based on another property that is not part of the `IComparable` definition for the list type.  Using `FirstOrDefault` is more generic, at the expense of performance.